# jsonserializationexception: cannot deserialize the current json object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

Tags: c#

I can't consume a REST service. A problem arises (in the title) when I call the API, in the following line:

```
var CuentaResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

It returns correctly, but during serialization is when I encounter the issue. Help please. 
**WEB API C#**

```
 [Route("api/Cuentas/ListadoCuentas")]
    public Modelos.Cuentas.Cuentas ListaCuentas()
    {
        string sql = "EXEC sp_cuentasSelect";
        EjecutarSql(sql);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(objDatos);

        foreach (DataRow item in objDatos.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta();
            cuenta.numeroCuenta = item["NumeroCuenta"].ToString();
            cuenta.nombreCuenta = item["NombreCuenta"].ToString();
            cuenta.cliente.nombreCliente = item["nombreCliente"].ToString();
            cuenta.tipoCuenta.tipoCuenta = item["tipoCuenta"].ToString();
            cuenta.tipoMoneda = item["tipoMoneda"].ToString();
            cuenta.esCuentaTercero = item["esCuentaTercero"].ToString();
            cuentas.ListaCuentas.Add(cuenta);
        }
        return cuentas;
    }
```

WEB MVC C#

```
    // GET: Cuenta
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        //var result = client.GetAsync("http:localhost:50665/api/Cuentas/ListadoCuentas").Result;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        //Definir formato de datos de solicitud
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //Enviando solicitud para encontrar el recurso de servicio REST de la API web Cuentas utilizando HttpClient
        HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/Cuentas/ListadoCuentas");

        // La verificación de la respuesta es exitosa o no, la cual se envía usando HttpClient
        if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //Almacenando los detalles de respuesta recibidos de la api web   
            var CuentaResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            //Deserializar la respuesta recibida de la API web y almacenarla en la lista de cuentas  
            list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cuenta>>(CuentaResponse);
        }
        return View(list);
    }
```

Comment: There is a SO site for Spanish (I'm guessing, I'm not good enough to tell the difference between Spanish and Portuguese): https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It's Spanish.. I suggested an edit with translation.. but you're suggesting is much better..

Comment: El comentario antes de el mío tiene un enlace para la página en español.  Debes de preguntar aya. Porque aquí se le hace más difícil a conseguir ayuda si nadie entiende lo que escribiste.